# ASP.NET Applications – Testing

Tags: asp.net, testing

We are building ASP.NET applications using VSTS (Visual Studio Team System) 2008 as IDE & C#.NET as Programming Language.

Would you please let me know whether we could test these applications using VSTS 2008?  If so would you please provide the details?

Are there any other VSTS integrated tools / third-party tools which we could use for testing the web applications.  The testing could be Unit/Functional/Load Testing etc.

Many thanks.

Regards,
Reshma.

Answer (score 1):

That question is a tough one.

If you did not separate your business logic from your UI logic in your web forms, no, this is not going to be easily testable. But that is not depending on VSTS or any other testing framework but on the 'qualility' and testability of your code solely.

If you really want to test your application, you should try to use the ASP.NET MVC framework. It's designed to being well testable, and if applied correctly you end up with clean, testable code.

Any testing framework (NUnit, MSpec, the VSTS-built in Framework etc.) will do just fine.

If you want to test your Web-GUI you may want to have a look at [Web UI Test studio](http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools.aspx) from Telerik. Even if I had very bad experience with their ASP.NET controls in terms of performance and testability, this testing tool seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to comment on the capabilities of Visual Studio Team System for testing rather than focus on the topic of how to conduct any particular type of testing. For instance, unit testing is a broad topic that includes many practices on how to design your software for testability and approaches to undertake in developing your code (like TDD - test driven development).

Visual Studio Team System 2008 includes a suite of testing tools including support for testing web applications.

You can:

- Build unit tests to test the code components of your application (provided you have designed your code to be testable,
- Build web tests that mimic browser behaviour by recording a browsing session and replaying it during a test run,
- Conduct load testing by simulating groups of users accessing your site.

You can learn more from:

- [A Unit Testing Walkthrough with Visual Studio Team Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28VS.80%29.aspx) (it's for Visual Studio 2005, but still applies to Visual Studio 2008)
- [Web and Load Testing with Visual Studio Team System](http://blogs.msdn.com/amit_chatterjee/archive/2009/01/29/web-and-load-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there is dedicated VS edition - [MSVS Test Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ivonna](http://sm-art.biz/Ivonna.aspx), integration and unit Asp.Net testing tool.